# how to jude the scroll direction (up down right left) in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

When I use `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell`, in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, some attributes should be set according to the direction of the tableview's scrolling direction. How do I get it?

Comment: Don't set them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Set them in a `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: but what to set in cellForRowAtIndexPath method is  the cell,such as image ,label , and so on ,then it will appear

Comment: Yes, but if you want behaviour or UI to change based on scrolling, you should do this in your `UIScrollViewDelegate`. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not guaranteed to be called during scrolling, nor is it guaranteed that the direction of scroll will be meaningful when it is called.

Comment: thank you very much. here is what i have done:                              1.customize a uitableviewcell, Channelcell
2.customize a uitableviewcontroller Zoomintableviewcontroller import Channelcell.h
3.Channelcell itself has images ,labels ,which has to be set some animation
4.Zoomintableviewcontroller will control certain animations  of each Channelcell
5. all the animation in 3 and 4 only take place when scroll up,that is , when a cell appears up from the bottom .
so, in which function to do animation and how to judge the direction to fit the "scroll up"

Comment: and when a "pull down" occurs, a cell may fall down from the top ,but all the animations are not wished to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `willDisplayCell` :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSInteger previousPresnetedCell = 0;

    if (indexPath.row < previousPresnetedCell) {

        NSLog(@" ** Scrolled up");

    } else {

        NSLog(@" ** Scrolled down");

    }

    previousPresnetedCell = indexPath.row;
}
```

Question is, how do you want to set the initial properties (before starting to scroll the tableView)?
You can detect it by simply use the scrolView delegate method 'scrollViewWillBeginDragging':

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    self.tableViewAlreadyScrolled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does not work? Are the logs not accurate? I tried it and it worked for me

Comment: ,sorry,it works,i did not set previousPresnetedCell = indexPath.row in a （if...else...）branch, thanks again

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Can you please accept the answer (mark 'v') if it indeed solved your problem? Thanks :)